# Ansible - List available hosts

Tags: ansible

I got some hosts in my ansible inventory which the ansible server cannot connect to (there is no pubkey deployed).

- How do I list all of them? (List unreachable hosts)
- Maybe there is a way to generate an inventory file with all of the hosts?

(the less elegant way is to write a playbook and to copy the command line output, but is there a better way?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To list them, you can use the `ping` module, and pipe the output :

```
ANSIBLE_NOCOWS=1 ansible -m ping all 2>&1  | grep 'FAILED => SSH' | cut -f 1 -d' '
```

If you want to generate an inventory, you can just redirect the output in a file :

```
ANSIBLE_NOCOWS=1 ansible -m ping all 2>&1  | grep 'FAILED => SSH' | cut -f 1 -d' ' > hosts_without_key
```

Then, you can use it later providing the `-i` switch to ansible commands :

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts_without_key deploy_keys.yml
```

If you can ssh using passwords, and assuming you have a key deploying playbook (e.g. `deploy_keys.yml`), you can issue :

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts_without_key deploy_keys.yml -kKu someuser
```

But if the point is to deploy keys on hosts that don't have them, remember Ansible is idempotent. It does no harm to execute the `deploy_keys.yml` playbook everywhere (it's just a bit longer).

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, ping is the solution I prefer.
So far the keys were in a separate password management tool, so I only needed a list of instances to look up and to temporarily add `ansible_ssh_pass` to the concerned servers in the inventory